# Problem with installing MiKTeX

Tags: miktex

I was trying to install MiKTeX 2.8.35553 and landed up with the following error.
[image]

Can anybody tell me the exact installation source ? Thanks in advancce...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiKTeX 2.8 was  replaced with MiKTeX 2.9… in october 2010. You should download the latest version from [MiKTeX home page](http://miktex.org/).

Comment: if i want to install the older version will that not work ?

Comment: I'm afraid not: the old binary files do not exist any more. Why the hell would you want to install  the old version?

Comment: thats because I have got 2.8 in my pen drive. Currently unable to install 2.9 because of poor net speed

Comment: I'm afraid there's no solution. You wouldn't be able to update packages to their present version. Maybe download at night while you sleep… Or ask at your university.